# directory permission error with postgresql

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, postgresql

hello I installed postgres in WSL Ubuntu 22.04.1 and every time I log in get this error 
`could not change directory to "/home/<user>": Permission denied`
[image: wsl]

how do I fix the denied permission?

Comment: Was a user account created in PostgreSQL at some point called `sci`? Alternatively, is there an Ubuntu user account named `sci`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by executing the following command.

`chmod og+rX /home /home/user`

Hope this helps others when `sudo apt install postgresql`

Comment: I got the error "operation not permitted"...

Comment: @AolongLi you just need to do the command with sudo